# 2- combination c++

Tags: c++, combinations

I have an array of n elements, I need to put all 2- combination of them into arrays of length 2. for example:

suppose comb is a 2 dimensional array.

```
n = 1,2,3
```

I need to put all 2- combinations to comb[i][j] like that:

```
comb[0][0] = {1}
comb[0][1] = {2}

comb[1][0] = {1}
comb[1][1] = {3}

comb[2][0] = {2}
comb[2][1] = {3}
```

I do not know how to write the code!
Thanks

My Answer:

The O(n!) answer: n = total number m= total possible answer

```
int m = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
    int first = a[i];
    for(int j = i+1 ; j < n ; j++){
        int second = a[j];
        comb[m][0] = first;
        comb[m][1] = second;
        ++m;
}
```

}

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried? Anyway, you should remove those braces.

Comment: I'm afraid if StackOverflow would be helpful for doing your homework ;-)

Comment: @g13n, SO can definitely give great help with homework, but if it's homework, you should be *doing* it yourself. Most of the time, all it takes is an idea to build on. If you come to get other people to do your homework, why did you enroll in the course in the first place?

Comment: what the hell is going on here ? who said that its homework? its a part of a project and I wanted to know the optimized solution for data more than 1000 000! . if you do not know the answer do not spam it !

Comment: @Bipario, I was merely asking because it has the looks of a homework question. Whether it is influences what type of answers you will receive.

Comment: @Bipario going berserk won't help your cause.

Comment: @Bipario: Your answer has better complexity than you're suggesting. It's actually `O(n^2)` rather than `O(n!)`. However, it will produce duplicate pairs if the elements in n are not unique, e.g. for `n = {1, 1, 1}` you will end up with `comb = {1,1},{1,1},{1,1}`. Is that desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is using the `next_permutation` function available in the STL library in order to generate all the possible permutations of your numbers, and then pick the first two elements of each one. Note that the sequence must be first sorted, as if not the previous permutations will be skipped.

```
int nums[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
while (next_permutation(nums, nums + 4)) {
    cout << nums[0] << ", " << nums[1] << endl;
}
```

Remember that you must `#include <algorithm>` to use this function.

Comment: thanks. I have many numbers, not just 3. so computing all the permutation costs alot of memory. The order is not important for me and I just want to store all the 2- combinations. Is there any other optimized way?

Comment: It doesn't matter how many numbers you have, as this uses no extra memory (the elements are rearranged in the original array)

Comment: Are you sure? so, I should only call the next_permutation and only select the first two elements of each permutation? what about the order of the algorithm?

Comment: @Bipario: this is an O(n!) algorithm, and generates a lot more rows than you need. fails if the numbers are not sorted. also I guess it's a too high-level solution for your homework. you shouldn't accept this as an answer.

Comment: I told you, it is not a homework! whatever ! any algorithm for this question should be O(n!)..

Comment: @Bipario, the problem is that it's getting permutations of a larger set than you need. For example, you'd be going through `{1,2,3,4}, {1,2,4,3}`, for just `{1,2}` in both cases if all you want is two elements.

Answer (score 1):

Can think of the following N^2 approach:

```
// Resulting combinations
vector<pair<int,int> > comb;
// Copy n into a double-ended queue - best would be for n to already be a deque
deque<int> Q(a.size());
copy(a.begin(), a.end(), Q.begin());
sort(Q.begin(), Q.end());

while(!Q.empty())
{
   // Get first element, remove it and equivalent elements
   int a = Q.front();
   while(Q.front() == a)
       Q.pop_front();

   // Find all unique combinations with first element
   int last=a;
   for(deque<int>::iterator it = Q.begin(); it != Q.end(); ++it)
   {
       if(*it != last)
           comb.push_back(pair<int,int>(a,*it));
        last = *it;
   }
}
```

Probably easy to optimize this further.

Comment: Think that an algortihm with worst-case time of less than `O(n^2)` will probably not be possible, since the output with unique numbers scales at `n^2`, e.g. there are 3 combinations for 3 and 45 combinations for 10 unique elements.

Comment: Thanks. This is a good answer. I have O(n!) answer , I post it now

Answer (score 0):

For each element in `n` indexed ith put every elements in `n` except the ith indexed jth in cell `comb[length(n) - i][j]`.

Comment: wrong indexes.. and please don't give a full solution for his homework.

Comment: @Karoly I must be tired I don't see the problem ?

Comment: compare your algo with his example

Comment: Well there is no point to give me hints ... Edit my answer if you want. Anyway I think my answer is enough to help the OP. My answer does not assume that 0 address the first element and is also not very explicit about j, but well the goal is to not give directly the answer...